# How to get user input for a python script and use it in another program?

Tags: python, youtube, user-input, pytube

I want to get user input used in another program as a input for url and path. But thats seems to be impossible.
#mymodule.py script

```
from pytube import YouTube
import pytube
# import check_avail 

class vdodownload:

    def __init__(self,url,path):
        self.url = url
        self.path = path


    def link(self):
        try:
            print(f'Downloading video: {YouTube(self.url).title}')
            # yt = check_avail.video(self.url,self.path)
            YouTube(self.url).streams.first().download(self.path)
            print(f'Downloaded video: {YouTube(self.url).title}')
        
        except pytube.exceptions.ExtractError:
             print(f'Video {self.url} is unavaialable, skipping.')
        # else:
        #      print(f'Downloading video: {self.url}')
        #      yt.streams.first().download(self.path)
        #      print(f'Downloaded video: {self.url}')
        
            
url = input("Enter the video URL: ")
path = input("Enter the path: ")

t = vdodownload(url,path)

t.link()
```

#check_avail.py script

```
from pytube import YouTube

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def video(url,path):
        y = YouTube(url) 
        # video1 = YouTube(url).streams.first().download(path)
        # print(f"title:{YouTube(url).title}, views:{YouTube(url).views}, Length:{YouTube(url).length}")
        print("Successfully done")    
        return video
else:
    def check(func):
        def parameters(u,v):
            print(f"title:{YouTube(u).title}, views:{YouTube(u).views}, Length:{YouTube(u).length}")
            return func(u,v)
        return parameters
        # return check

    def filtering(func):
        def param(u,v):
            check1 = YouTube(u).streams.filter(type='video',progressive=True,file_extension='mp4')
            print(check1)
            return func(u,v)
        return param
    # return filtering

    @filtering
    @check
    def video(url,path):
        y = YouTube(url) 
    # video1 = YouTube(url).streams.first().download(path)
        print("Success") 
        return video  


url = input("Enter input url here: ")
path = input("Enter path here: ")

video(url,path)
```

I want to get user input from another python script named mymodule.py for check_avail.py input for url and path. I have searched online but no good answer.
can anyone help me?

Comment: If you are importing check_avail.py then you probably don't want to get input or call `video()` so those you might want to revisit your `if __name__ == "__main__":` block. Also note that at the moment you `return video` and that is likely not what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

After so many search I found an answer.
If you are creating a class of methods in a python program and use user-defined variables from another python script you have to create a object in that python script from where you need to import it.

<--create scrpit1.py-->

```
from pytube import YouTube
def video(url,path):
    y = YouTube(url) 
    video1 = YouTube(url).streams.first().download(path)
    print("Success") 
    return video  


url = input("Enter input url here: ")
path = input("Enter path here: ")

<---- Create a object here so that you can import and use anywhere-->
t = video(url,path)
```

script2.py

<---Use imported variables-->

```
from pytube import YouTube
import pytube
# import check_avail 

class vdodownload:

<-- accessing it from another script and initialise to another variable-->
    def __init__(self,url,path):
        self.url = t.url
        self.path = t.path

<-- or you can directly use it here by giving t.url -->
    def link(self):
        try:
            print(f'Downloading video: {YouTube(t.url).title}')
            # yt = check_avail.video(t.url,t.path)
            YouTube(t.url).streams.first().download(t.path)
            print(f'Downloaded video: {YouTube(t.url).title}')
```

This is one way of doing it. Pls correct it if any changes needed.